# Check if a firewall rule exists using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

I need to check if a firewall rule exists for a certain application, and if it doesn't then create one. I know how to create one but not how to check if one already exists.

Comment: -1 We help to fix provided code, not write it for you here on SO. Please provide something that you have tried or found that could potentially complete this task.

Comment: I tried Get-NetFirewallRule -Display "ApplicationName"

Answer (score 4):

Can you try

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName <String[]>
```

So for, say, Microsoft Photos, you'd use

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Microsoft Photos"
```

Comment: The argument is -Display and I didn't have any luck.  I got the error "InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule)"

Comment: `-Display` is ambiguous (can refer to `-DisplayName` and `-DisplayGroup`), use `-DisplayName` as in the example

Comment: I don't think I understand. Have you tried the code above, and replaced "Microsoft Photos" with your application's name? You can not use just -Display as a parameter

Comment: Eadoh your command worked. It didn't for Cortana and a couple other applications though. Thanks

Comment: Cortana will have a weird display name, something like @{Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.6.1.52_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.Cortana/resources/DisplayName}. What you can do is use Get-NetFirewallRule -All, and then search for "cortana" in the output to find it's real display name.You can do the same for other apps as well.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. I would not mind if you vote up, as well :D

Comment: @Eedoh Can't accept answers on posts that have been marked duplicate :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Haha. Haven't seen that at the time I asked for it :D